# find info string inside files that are located in subdirectoies

Tags: macos, unix

im on OSX , and i have a folder that contains around 200 .bundle files ( they are actually folders) inside each .bundle folder  there is Info.plist -xml text.
inside each info.plist im looing for a specific string something like CFBundleExecutable and another string  key>CFBundleGetInfoString
i need the text after the CFBundleExecutable and the text after the CFBundleGetInfoString

I want to create a log that contains a .bundle file name and its version next to it.

so the output should look like

```
a.bundle version 1.0.1
b.bundle version 1.0.1
c.bundle version 1.2.2
```

i tried awk however after find but with no results...

Comment: How about showing us the salient parts of an info.plist file? Or telling us what you mean by "the text after" - does this mean on the same line to the right of it? Or on the following line? Or 17 lines later?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of Python's built-in [plistlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/plistlib.html) module to easily parse plists.  Here's a simpleminded one-liner to get you started:

```
find . -name Info.plist \
-execdir python -c 'import plistlib; \
       pl = plistlib.readPlist("Info.plist") ; \
       print("{0} version {1}".format(pl.get("CFBundleExecutable", "<none>"), \
                                      pl.get("CFBundleGetInfoString", "<none>")))' ';'
```

Comment: What's not "unix" about it?  Plists are not a general "unix-wide" file format; they came from NeXT and its successor, OS X.  Hence, they are not well-supported in traditional Unix tools.  And both `find` and `python` are part of standard OS X releases.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - the script runs and does the trick , and i thank you for that. my question was if that was possible to that same thing with a loop and traditional sed or awk.

Comment: Info.plists are generally written in a dialect of XML, a notoriously tricky serialization format to parse correctly in all cases.  There are many XML parser tools out there. Trying to parse XML with sed or awk is just asking for trouble.  More generally, plists can actually be written in other formats, as well, including a binary representation.  The `plistlib` in Python 3.4 can handle them all.  Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: Glad to be of help. On Stackoverflow, if you post a question, you should either mark an answer as accepted or keep refining your question until you get an acceptable answer.